# Pan not working in Swift 3

Tags: xcode, swift3, pan

I am trying to make a set of views draggable. I dragged a `Pan Gesture Recognizer` into the view called `Apps`. My current code doesn't work.

```
@IBAction func MoveApp(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        sender.view!.center = CGPoint(x: sender.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: sender.view!.center.y + translation.y)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
}
```

[views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL2qN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the code in the ibaction method with the following code. That worked for me.

```
@IBAction func moveApp(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let point = sender.location(in: view)
        sender.view?.center = point
    }
```